# Load Social Network Data into Neo4J

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset similar to Twitter's graph. The data is in the following form:

```
<user-id1> <List of ids which he follows separated by spaces>
<user-id2> <List of ids which he follows separated by spaces>
...
```

I want to model this in the form of a unidirectional graph, expressed in the cypher syntax as:

```
(A:Follower)-[:FOLLOWS]->(B:Followee)
```

The same user can appear more than once in the dataset as he might be in the friend list of more than one person, and he might also have his friend list as part of the data set. The challenge here is to make sure that there are no duplicate nodes for any user. And if the user appears as a Follower and Followee both in the data set, then the node's label should have both the values, i.e., Follower:Followee. There are about 980k nodes in the graph and size of dataset is 1.4 GB.

I am not sure if Cypher's load CSV will work here because each line of the dataset has a variable number of columns making it impossible to write a query to generate the nodes for each of the columns. So what would be the best way to import this data into Neo4j without creating any duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did actually exactly the same for the [friendster dataset](https://archive.org/details/friendster-dataset-201107), which has almost the same format as yours.

There the separator for the many friends was ":".

The queries I used there, are these:

```
create index on :User(id);

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/michael/import/friendster/friends-000______.txt" as line FIELDTERMINATOR ":"
MERGE (u1:User {id:line[0]})
;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/michael/import/friendster/friends-000______.txt" as line FIELDTERMINATOR ":"
WITH line[1] as id2
WHERE id2 <> '' AND id2 <> 'private' AND id2 <> 'notfound'
UNWIND split(id2,",") as id
WITH distinct id
MERGE (:User {id:id})
;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/michael/import/friendster/friends-000______.txt" as line FIELDTERMINATOR ":"
WITH line[0] as id1, line[1] as id2
WHERE id2 <> '' AND id2 <> 'private' AND id2 <> 'notfound'
MATCH (u1:User {id:id1})
UNWIND split(id2,",") as id 
MATCH (u2:User {id:id})
CREATE (u1)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(u2)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out. I also need to distinguish between the Follower and Followee by different labels. I have added ON MATCH and ON CREATE clauses and trying this out. BTW, what was the total size of your dataset, and how much time it took for you to import it? I am getting out of memory errors, I have set the max heap size to 2GB.